# Algorithm to distribute n people in unique pairs over n-1 days

Tags: java, python, algorithm, kotlin, logic

I`m trying to create an algorithm which creates unique pairs out of an even number of n people. Afterwards it should partition these pairs into n-1 days. so every day, every person meets someone else. pairs shouldn't be duplicated. the algorithm should provide a different solution every time it runs.

e.g.
my start array is [1,2,3,4] - this gets converted into following pairs:

```
[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],
      [2,3],[2,4],
            [3,4]
```

now these pairs need to be split up between n-1 days like this

```
day 1 [1,2] & [3,4]
day 2 [1,3] & [2,4]
day 3 [1,4] & [2,3]
```

thanks for your help!

**UPDATE**

Thanks to the answers I wrote this solution

```
    fun createDates(userIds: List<Int>): List<DateEntity> {
        val dates = ArrayList<DateEntity>()

        val userCount = userIds.size
        val days = userCount - 1
        val half = userCount / 2

        val mutableUsers = userIds.toMutableList()

        for (day in 0 until days) {
            val firstHalf = mutableUsers.slice(0 until half)
            val secondHalf = mutableUsers.slice(half until userCount).reversed()

            for (i in firstHalf.indices) {
                dates.add(DateEntity(day, firstHalf[i], secondHalf[i]))
            }
            // rotating the array
            mutableUsers.add(1, mutableUsers.removeLast())
        }
        return dates
    }
```

Comment: You may find an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65911162/5237560

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Round-robin algorithm:

Put people in two rows.

Every day person from the top row is paired with corresponding one from lower row.
If number of persons is odd, one person waits for a day.

```
day 1
A B C
D E F
A:D B:E C:F
```

After the day shift all but the first person in cyclic manner:

```
day 2
A D B
E F C
A:E D:F B:C 

day 3
A E D
F C B
A:F E:C D:B
```

and so on.

Comment: thank you very much, you showed me the correct way!

Answer (score 1):

This code simply performs [the algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66052898/1243641) described by MBo.

```js
const cycle = (n, xs) => 
  [... xs .slice (n % xs .length), ... xs .slice (0, n % xs .length)]

const pairs = (xs) =>
  xs.length < 2 ? [] : [[xs [0], xs [xs .length - 1]], ...pairs (xs .slice (1, -1))]

const roundRobin = ([x, ...xs]) => 
  Array.from(xs, (_, i) => pairs ([x, ...cycle(i, xs)]))

console .log (roundRobin ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])) //=>
// (1 - 6)  &  (2 - 5)  &  (3 - 4)
// (1 - 2)  &  (3 - 6)  &  (4 - 5)
// (1 - 3)  &  (4 - 2)  &  (5 - 6)
// (1 - 4)  &  (5 - 3)  &  (6 - 2)
// (1 - 5)  &  (6 - 4)  &  (2 - 3)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

`cycle` just cycles an array `n` places, so that, for instance, `cycle (2, ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])` yields `['c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b']`.  `pairs` puts into pairs the two elements from the ends of the array and then the two next to them, and so forth.  `pairs (['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'])` yields `[['a', 'f'], ['b', 'e'], ['c', 'd']]`.

We combine these in `roundRobin`,  For each day, we remove the first value, cycle the remaining ones, put the first value back, and turn the list into pairs.

If you want additional randomness, I would suggest simply shuffling the array before you start.

If you want to allow an odd number of participants, with one sitting out each time, I would add a dedicated sitting-out participant, which will then be paired each day with a different participant.

Comment: thank you for your example! it helped a lot!